# как обратиться к самомму итератору vector'a?

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<std::string> list {};

for (vector<string>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)
{
   string do_string(*i);
   if (i % 2 == 0) //ошибка компиляции no match for 'operator%' in 'i % 2'
   {
   }
}
```

Нужно выяснить какое значение итератора четное, а какое нечетное.

Comment: Сразу итерируйте по индексу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядковый номер? Вычитайте begin:

```
(i - begin(list)) % 2 == 0
```

Comment: лучше std::distance

Comment: int t = i-list.begin(); if (t %2 == 0)